# Kotlin - Check if an object implements a specific interface

Tags: kotlin

Say I have some data class like:

```
data class NameCreated(
    val index: Float,
    val name: String
) : ESEventPayload
```

I then have some method where I want to return true if the Event's type in `<Event<out Any>>` is implementing `ESEventPayload`.

So for example:

```
fun isItUsing(message: AcknowledgeableMessage<Event<out Any>>): Boolean =
```

I was hoping something like this would work, but it's not:

```
if (ESEventPayload::class.java.isAssignableFrom(message.body.payloadType::class.java)) {
   println("It's using the interface")
} else {
   println("It isn't using")
}
```

How do I go about doing this in Kotlin?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As you need to check object's class it seems as bad architecture. Can you explain why do you need that?

Comment: I have different types of Events (as modelled with different data classes) - I only want to perform a specific action on ones that behave a specific way - i.e. have that specific interface `ESEventPayload`.

Comment: Why couldn't you use `is` or `as` ?

Comment: Ahh i just realised I was `ESEventPayload` was the `data class` not the interface. All good. - `is` worked, or the longer `<interface>.isAssignableFrom<checkingObject>`. I presume these 2 are the same??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `is` operator, which simply looks like:

```
if (something is ESEventPayload) { ... }
```

There is no reason here to use `isAssignableFrom`.  In fact it has the negative consequence of not smart casting.  When using `is` you can...

```
if (something is ESEventPayload) {
   // something here is now smart cast as ESEventPayload, no casting needed
   println(something.eventPayloadMemberOrMethod) 
}
```

See:  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Answer (score 0):

for some reason it didn't work on me.

when an object implementing A,B,C

trying type checking with is statement

ex : Some is B. Sometime fail to detect

it work at first time but sometime it didn't on the second time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).